# #show branch in terminal with .bashrc

Tags: git, bash, terminal

I am using the following .bashrc file. The tab completion works fine. However. The second piece of code the #show branch is not being so nice. When I first set it up and sourced it it worked fine. My terminal window it was is at the home location would look something like this `[~]$` and when its in a branch something like `[direcorty (master)]$` However when I opened a new tab window of terminal it goes back to something like `Anders-imac:~ anderskitson$` How do I get the Show branch in status line to stay.

```
#Git tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash
# Show branch in status line
PS1='[\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not staying is likely because your terminal is using `.bash_profile` rather than your `.bashrc`.

I would create a link to your `.bashrc` file so that all new terminal windows will use that code from a single `.bashrc` file:

```
mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile.bak
ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile
```

`mv` = move, this will backup your current .bash_profile in case you have something important in there you want to keep.
`ln -s` = create a symbolic link from .bashrc to .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your shells are login shells?  If they are, `.bashrc` doesn't necessarily get read.  Try making a similar change in your `.bash_profile`, or simply source `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile`.